# Web user authentication methods

Tags: web-development, security, database

Is there any method besides using a DB with username and password for authenticating a user?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how users access the site, you might be able to authenticate simply by their IP address.

There is also HTTP authentication, both [basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) and [digest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication).

But if you need to differentiate between multiple users then these need to be stored somewhere, and regardless of the method used, this is a "database".

Answer (score 1):

Oh boy are there! OAuth (Facebook, Google, Twitter), SAML, LDAP, PAM, HTTP Basic, HTTP Client Certificate, IP restriction, 2-Factor authentication, RSA token, biometrics.

Comment: I like the rundown. Very impressive! I would like to have seen a couple of paragraphs that would categorize these by advantage and when and how to chose one or a set of options. Not a lot, just a bit more to be helpful and give a direction to run in. Clearly, you know what you are doing! The user does not- at least not to the degree you do. Here is an opportunity to add a bit of value. Thanks in advance!

Comment: BTW- I want to say I like your answers. I wrote my comment to be constructive and not critical. Please keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using some eternal authentication like OAuth http://oauth.net/ or Facebook Login https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.1

I believe OAuth still requires SQL usage though.